# Accessing POST data in a django CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to use PurchaseCreateView to create a Purchase instance and then go on to update the Ingredients model

The following code is throwing a MultiValueDictKey error.

I CANNOT work out how to fix this. Can anyone help?

Here are my Models:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "inventory"

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def available(self):
        return all(x.enough() for x in self.reciperequirements_set.all())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class RecipeRequirements(models.Model):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def enough(self):
        return self.quantity <= self.ingredient.quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.menu_item} requires {self.ingredient}"

class Purchase(models.Model):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.menu_item} purchased at {self.timestamp}"`
```

My Views:

```
    class PurchaseCreateView(CreateView):
        template_name = "inventory/purchase_form.html"
        model = Purchase
        fields = "__all__"
        success_url = reverse_lazy("home")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["menu_items"] = [x for x in MenuItem.objects.all() if x.available()]
        return context

    def post(self, request):
        menu_item_id = request.POST["menuitem"]
        menu_item = MenuItem.objects.get(pk=menu_item_id)
        purchase = Purchase(menu_item=menu_item)
        purchase.save()
```

and the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>New purchase</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h2>Add a new purchase</h2>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select>
        {% for menu_item in menu_items %}
        <option name="menuitem" value="{{menu_item.id}}">{{menu_item.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Im not sure why some of the code is not in the code block!!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A change to the html form template led me to new error codes which I was able to work with to solve the issue!!  (Although I'm not quite sure why...)

Comment: I think moving the name value in the form to the select tag let me access the POST data I was trying to get hold of. On to the next problem to solve....

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute has to be set on `select` tag, not `option`...

```html
{% block content %}

<h2>Add a new purchase</h2>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="menuitem">
        {% for menu_item in menu_items %}
        <option value="{{menu_item.id}}">{{menu_item.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Documentation about `select` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Thank you, doing that has lead me to several changes that have solved the problem!!!